# Do we know all non-perfect fields?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

Except the (rather famous) example $\mathbb F_p(t)= \{ \frac{f(t)}{g(t)}:\ f,g \in \mathbb F_p[t],\ g\neq 0 \}$, which has the inseparable extension containing the one multiple root of $x^p- t$. Do we know other examples of inseparable extensions?

It seems unfortunate if we had a definition of separability only because of one example. So I suspect there are more, or, at least, there is more to this specific example.

Comment: I remember only that finite fields and fields with characeristic $0$ are perfect. So, non-perfect fields must at least be quite special.

Comment: The theorem that @Peter quotes does indeed mean that most fields you encounter in introductory field theory will be perfect, and that the fields of rational functions in positive characteristic are, in some sense, the "simplest" non-perfect fields. But with only my gut to go on, I sincerely doubt that non-perfect fields are in any way "rare" other than what this theorem tells us.

Comment: @Peter Another example: algebraically closed fields are trivially perfect.

Comment: @Arthur What theorem are you referring to? I am looking for infinite fields of characteristic $p>0$ other than $\mathbb F_p(t)$, so far in all the references that I checked, this is the only example shown.